# Soup.find() returning None

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use soup.find() to scrape the following Wayfair link, but it doesn't come up with any results. I am new to HTML and maybe I am passing in the wrong argument.

Link: [https://www.wayfair.com/furniture/sb2/office-chairs-on-sale-c478390-a69117~8-a69117~12.html?itemsperpage=96&sortby=2&curpage=2](https://www.wayfair.com/furniture/sb2/office-chairs-on-sale-c478390-a69117%7E8-a69117%7E12.html?itemsperpage=96&sortby=2&curpage=2)

Here is my code, with comments about what I think each section should be doing.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.wayfair.com/furniture/sb2/office-chairs-on-sale-c478390-a69117~8-a69117~12.html?itemsperpage=96&sortby=2&curpage=2"  # Wayfair URL
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
results = soup.find(id="sf-ui-browse::application")  # using soup.find to grab HTML element which holds all items on page
items = results.find_all("a", class_="_1yxeg5wb_6101")  # finds each item within results

for item in items:  # iterate through all items
    link = None  # need to figure out how to get link
    sale_price = item.find_all("span", class_="oakhm627_6101 oakhm6y5_6101 oakhm610g_6101 oakhm6aj_6101")  # grab sale price
    original_price = sale_price.find('s'.get_text())  # grab original price
```

I chose to write results = soup.find(id="sf-ui-browse::application") because of this: [image]

I chose to write items = results.find_all("a", class_="_1yxeg5wb_6101") because of this: [image]

I chose to write sale_price = item.find_all("span", class_="oakhm627_6101 oakhm6y5_6101 oakhm610g_6101 oakhm6aj_6101") because of this: [image]

Lastly, I chose to write original_price = sale_price.find('s'.get_text()) because of this: [image]

Comment: I think this is because you use `requests` (which cannot process javascript) to fetch the page.

Comment: If @JohnGordon is right, consider using Selenium.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get any results because the website requires headers to go through, and has CloudFlare protection to filter unauthorized requests.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint
import requests

url = "https://www.wayfair.com/furniture/sb2/office-chairs-on-sale-c478390-a69117~8-a69117~12.html?itemsperpage=96&sortby=2&curpage=2"  # Wayfair URL
headers = {
    'Cookie': 'CSNUtId=23e17d3a-64b4-62a8-846e-cc0ad404eb02; ExCSNUtId=23e17d3a-64b4-62a8-846e-cc0ad404eb02; vid=23e17d3a-64b4-62a8-846e-cc0ad404eb02; SFSID=c2eab9d475e64d7b97629a772b4c663d; canary=0; WFDC=DSM; serverUAInfo=%7B%22browser%22%3A%22Google%20Chrome%22%2C%22browserVersion%22%3A114%2C%22OS%22%3A%22Linux%22%2C%22OSVersion%22%3A%22%22%2C%22isMobile%22%3Afalse%2C%22isTablet%22%3Afalse%2C%22isTouch%22%3Afalse%7D; __px_jnfwwtr_5=disable; CSN_CSRF=cb9faa96f2d4fbd40eaf171d4a26f00b20ffe2b07863b3c024078b462e7f0731; __cf_bm=Jper6uQ43i4hVvT1NjVWf3HKUcAlE0M9ikPWZRtuWh8-1689543337-0-AeNj0jlZzqtg13tHs23bSM4eYQSv5zAx61wGElTxo3oKqFQTF8cAdbcIh3xrBlHqCNkSSf2V+p3DwKq1BLjXpbE=; pxcts=b47d1888-2420-11ee-ab77-7765757a4a6a; _pxvid=b368d929-2420-11ee-b86b-193530f24b45; __ssid=f517769c836433001212c668d850d4b; _pxhd=m56Oxdmf1lsxFbwem3B4AeAvry4vDCT28djyNds345kfiHb0TDTiBkn/klvgsB5DIawz5j/HEmx5jCSJqm9LAw==:coL9AYhnxytjQSKS9smWBSA0B72rrNhlW-IYDIi4AhqUbTove0vX-G8B/drQM91LNJwUFpWAKbfiDdgpW-uGIJ6KeH0/FfukIgyGkJprJX4=; waychatShouldShowChatWindow=false; hideGoogleYolo=true; cjConsent=MHxOfDB8Tnww; cjUser=5ed9a5b8-3d45-4f1a-ba9c-90803541b002; _dpm_ses.15e8=*; sm_uuid=1689544115557; __attentive_id=d5117048ca2a4d89b4e2ea904cde8575; __attentive_cco=1689543342274; _tt_enable_cookie=1; _ttp=8nGdaUwiW72Yim-dM7lPbiJ361I; __attentive_ss_referrer=ORGANIC; IR_gbd=wayfair.com; rskxRunCookie=0; rCookie=ltbtw6jl1agqkih1sf5q4glk5yheqi; _gcl_au=1.1.1237726547.1689543343; _gid=GA1.2.1146081951.1689543343; __attentive_dv=1; _px3=7f5140838f358d7e2dfc2b848789b8f6b814e1f8ac3525d4c72070faa8cd23d5:1ZrU1FcgOYaXLoyMuUDi825/e/x7Fc3SQ1nW2ivMG4ifwLLI7cbcDOjZSIpnaPPWxNtGp6/Tw3atCJybjey6Wg==:1000:iMefzQRh7HrJDdTXqlryr2repqbX5rKzdPa2JhbHQBoyrVZ+WRUlwc6yY8YTDfHvDQNnIyVqhCntqvy8B2i2rHUcyFKte0RHCUwRhlW0LeIrQ0p29909TMnVDDmY/1+o4Dbll6V721o0eDLjYLFjphdCy2Qj/7wKvvlr2cNBlNXth1IqwkxfvWRfYPXaMwPisOHR+V9ot3UF8cNDs6IZDA==; _ga_0GV7WXFNMT=GS1.1.1689543342.1.1.1689543849.60.0.0; _dpm_id.15e8=c289da24-6db4-434d-99c3-d3e8e8231aca.1689543342.1.1689543850.1689543342.c60037e7-cc76-4e12-bcc3-b7b37aa5f83c; CSNPersist=page_of_visit%3D20; IR_12051=1689543850773%7C0%7C1689543850773%7C%7C; IR_PI=b7334dae-2420-11ee-adea-d3c413a970a3%7C1689630250773; lastRskxRun=1689543850888; _ga=GA1.2.1688151231.1689543343; _gat_gtag_UA_2081664_4=1; __attentive_pv=4; CSN=g_countryCode%3DUS%26g_zip%3D67346%26CLVW%3D10; otx=I+F9OmS0ZKWUT+xq3IpbAg==',
    'Host': 'www.wayfair.com',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}
page = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")
for result in page.find_all('div', {'class': 'TrackedProductCardWrapper-extendedInView'}):  # using soup.find_all to grab results elements and iterating overthem
    pprint({
        'link': result.find('a').get('href'),
        'sale price': result.find('div', {'class': 'SFPrice'}).find_all('span')[-1].text if result.find('div', {'class': 'SFPrice'}) and result.find('div', {'class': 'SFPrice'}).find_all('span') else '',
        'original price': result.find('div', {'class': 'SFPrice'}).find('s').text if result.find('div', {'class': 'SFPrice'}) and result.find('div', {'class': 'SFPrice'}).find('s') else '',
    })
```

Each page only has 12 items in the page source, whereas other results are lazy-loaded using JavaScript. The next you run this code, make sure to open the website once at least and replace this cookie with your latest cookie, as my cookie might not work for you.

Output:

```
{'link': 'https://www.wayfair.com/furniture/pdp/inbox-zero-isobela-ergonomic-executive-chair-w011389176.html',
 'original price': '$102.99',
 'sale price': '$89.99'}
{'link': 'https://www.wayfair.com/furniture/pdp/inbox-zero-gerno-mesh-task-chair-w008221201.html',
 'original price': '',
 'sale price': '$89.99'}
{'link': 'https://www.wayfair.com/furniture/pdp/inbox-zero-janazia-mesh-task-chair-w008222281.html',
 'original price': '',
 'sale price': '$89.99'}
{'link': 'https://www.wayfair.com/furniture/pdp/national-public-seating-height-adjustable-stool-with-backrest-np1027.html?piid=7207901',
 'original price': '$160.00',
 'sale price': '$90.04'}
{'link': 'https://www.wayfair.com/furniture/pdp/modway-advance-mesh-desk-chair-w006114938.html?piid=91652095',
 'original price': '$97.99',
 'sale price': '$90.56'}
{'link': 'https://www.wayfair.com/furniture/pdp/inbox-zero-jahlaya-mesh-task-chair-w008222864.html',
 'original price': '',
 'sale price': '$90.99'}
{'link': 'https://www.wayfair.com/furniture/pdp/inbox-zero-ishwaq-mesh-task-chair-w011389584.html',
 'original price': '$98.99',
 'sale price': '$91.99'}
{'link': 'https://www.wayfair.com/furniture/pdp/inbox-zero-lataija-task-chair-w100137459.html?piid=325726212',
 'original price': '$116.99',
 'sale price': '$91.99'}
{'link': 'https://www.wayfair.com/furniture/pdp/wade-logan-akimasa-task-chair-w008808250.html?piid=517020718%2C517020705',
 'original price': '$218.40',
 'sale price': '$92.99'}
{'link': 'https://www.wayfair.com/furniture/pdp/inbox-zero-orpha-executive-chair-w100237171.html?piid=320959130',
 'original price': '$109.99',
 'sale price': '$92.99'}
{'link': 'https://www.wayfair.com/furniture/pdp/latitude-run-everley-task-chair-w002958364.html?piid=127379374',
 'original price': '$99.00',
 'sale price': '$92.99'}
{'link': 'https://www.wayfair.com/furniture/pdp/wrought-studio-deasja-mesh-task-chair-w011224817.html',
 'original price': '$95.70',
 'sale price': '$92.99'}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! How would I fix the issue of it only doing 12 items, and how would I automate it to run across every item for multiple pages of items? Lastly, how can I add my own cookie? I used inspect and found a cookie value but it stopped after the CSNU and the ExCSNU whereas yours was much longer.

Comment: Inspect the element, go to Network Tab there, reload the page, and you'll see the page request and associated cookie. For other elements, you can look deep into the page source (Ctrl+U) rather than inspect element, it is in script tags I think, Regex can be utilized to get the data from there.